# Enum as state for log parsing

Tags: enum, rust

I have a [small project](https://github.com/JoshRagem/pg_crunch) to help me analyze query latency from PostgreSQL statement logging.

It's my first time writing anything real in Rust and I think it could be improved in several ways. My question here is about this code from `scanner.rs`:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, SipHasher, Hasher};
use regex::Regex;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::string::String;
use std;
use csv::Writer;

pub enum CrunchState {
    Scanning(HashMap<i32,String>, Writer<std::io::Stdout>),
    CurrentQuery(Vec<String>, i32, HashMap<i32,String>, Writer<std::io::Stdout>)
}

enum MatchResult {
    Ignore,
    QueryStart(i32, String),
    Duration(i32, String)
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref REGLS: Regex = Regex::new(r"^2016").unwrap();
    static ref REPID: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d{2,3}\((\d+)\):").unwrap();
    static ref REDURATION: Regex = Regex::new(r"duration: ([0-9.]+) ms").unwrap();
    static ref RESTATEMENT: Regex = Regex::new(r"(?:execute.*|statement):(.*)").unwrap();
}

pub fn init_state() -> CrunchState {
    let csv_writer: Writer<std::io::Stdout> = Writer::from_writer(std::io::stdout());
    CrunchState::Scanning(HashMap::new(), csv_writer)
}

pub fn process_line(line:String, state:CrunchState) -> CrunchState {
    match state {
        CrunchState::Scanning(mut pid_to_query, mut csv_writer) => {
            match analyze_line(line) {
                MatchResult::Ignore => CrunchState::Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer),
                MatchResult::QueryStart(pid, query_begin) => {
                    let query_parts = vec![query_begin];
                    CrunchState::CurrentQuery(query_parts, pid, pid_to_query, csv_writer)
                },
                MatchResult::Duration(pid, duration) => {
                    match pid_to_query.remove(&pid) {
                        Some(full_query) => {
                            let mut hasher = SipHasher::new();
                            full_query.hash(&mut hasher);
                            let qhash = hasher.finish();
                            let result = csv_writer.encode((pid, duration, qhash, &full_query));
                            assert!(result.is_ok());
                        },
                        None => {
                            // dangling duration
                        }
                    };
                    CrunchState::Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer)
                }
            }
        },
        CrunchState::CurrentQuery(mut query_parts, pid, mut pid_to_query, csv_writer) => {
            if !REGLS.is_match(&line) {
                query_parts.push(line);
                CrunchState::CurrentQuery(query_parts, pid, pid_to_query, csv_writer)
            } else {
                let full_query = query_parts.iter().fold("".to_string(), |acc, s| acc + s);
                pid_to_query.insert(pid, full_query);
                process_line(line, CrunchState::Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer))
            }
        }
    }
}

fn analyze_line(line:String) -> MatchResult {
    if REGLS.is_match(&line) {
        match REPID.captures_iter(&line).nth(0) {
            Some(cap) => {
                let pid: &str = cap.at(1).unwrap();
                if REDURATION.is_match(&line) {
                    let duration: &str = REDURATION.captures_iter(&line).nth(0).unwrap().at(1).unwrap();
                    MatchResult::Duration(pid.parse::<i32>().unwrap(), duration.to_string())
                } else if RESTATEMENT.is_match(&line) {
                    let statement: &str = RESTATEMENT.captures_iter(&line).nth(0).unwrap().at(1).unwrap();
                    MatchResult::QueryStart(pid.parse::<i32>().unwrap(), statement.to_string())
                } else {
                    MatchResult::Ignore
                }
            },
            None => {
                MatchResult::Ignore
            }
        }
    } else {
        MatchResult::Ignore
    }
}
```

For reference `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "pg_crunch"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Joshua Barney <barney@whoop.com>"]

[dependencies]
regex = "0.1.80"
lazy_static = "0.2.1"
csv = "0.14.7"
```

Since you can put data into enums, I figured that would be a great way of building a little state machine.

It runs and works correctly, but I'm worried about returning a new `CrunchState` enum for every call to `process_line`, especially when most lines should result in `CrunchState::Ignore` and not alter the state. What can I do better than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The compiler warnings tell me that `SipHasher` has been deprecated; use `DefaultHasher` instead.
2. Check out [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). The code has issues with missing spaces after `:` and `,`.
3. Use `lines` on `stdin` instead of reimplementing it.

**main.rs**

```
extern crate pg_crunch;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use pg_crunch::scanner::CrunchState;

fn main() {
    let mut state = CrunchState::new();

    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        match line {
            Ok(line) => state = state.process_line(line),
            Err(error) => println!("error: {}", error),
        }
    }
}
```

**scanner.rs**

1. Don't use `String`; it's already imported. I'd probably prefer to import specific modules or types instead of referring to `std`.
2. You can create methods on enums just like on structs. `new` and `process_line` really feel like methods to me.
3. Accept a `&str` instead of a `String` unless you make use of the allocation. `analyze_line` is a good example.
4. Create a tiny helper method for getting the hash.
5. Consider glob-importing your enum into methods that deal with them heavily.
6. Use `if let` when there's only one interesting match arm.
7. Use `collect` to combine multiple strings from an iterator.
8. Avoid Hungarian notation (where you encode the type of something into the name of the variable). The regexen don't need to be prefixed with `RE`.
9. Don't provide explicit types unless you are required. `: Writer<std::io::Stdout>` is a good example.
10. There's no need for the turbofish when the type is constrained by the struct you are putting the value in.
11. Instead of `assert!`, call `expect` on the `Result`. This prints the error message *and* lets you add a bit more context.
12. Try to avoid doing multiple regex calls for the same input. For example, calling `is_match` is redundant if you are also going to call `captures_iter`. You should be able to tell if it matched by the result of `captures_iter`.

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::{self, Stdout};

use regex::Regex;
use csv::Writer;

pub enum CrunchState {
    Scanning(HashMap<i32, String>, Writer<Stdout>),
    CurrentQuery(Vec<String>, i32, HashMap<i32, String>, Writer<Stdout>),
}

fn one_shot_hash(full_query: &str) -> u64 {
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    full_query.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}

impl CrunchState {
    pub fn new() -> CrunchState {
        let csv_writer = Writer::from_writer(io::stdout());
        CrunchState::Scanning(HashMap::new(), csv_writer)
    }

    pub fn process_line(self, line: String) -> CrunchState {
        use self::CrunchState::*;
        use self::MatchResult::*;

        match self {
            Scanning(mut pid_to_query, mut csv_writer) => {
                match analyze_line(&line) {
                    Ignore => Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer),
                    QueryStart(pid, query_begin) => {
                        let query_parts = vec![query_begin];
                        CurrentQuery(query_parts, pid, pid_to_query, csv_writer)
                    }
                    Duration(pid, duration) => {
                        if let Some(full_query) = pid_to_query.remove(&pid) {
                            let query_hash = one_shot_hash(&full_query);
                            let result = csv_writer.encode((pid, duration, query_hash, &full_query));
                            result.expect("Unable to write result");
                        }
                        Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer)
                    }
                }
            }
            CurrentQuery(mut query_parts, pid, mut pid_to_query, csv_writer) => {
                if !GLS.is_match(&line) {
                    query_parts.push(line);
                    CurrentQuery(query_parts, pid, pid_to_query, csv_writer)
                } else {
                    let full_query = query_parts.into_iter().collect();
                    pid_to_query.insert(pid, full_query);
                    Scanning(pid_to_query, csv_writer).process_line(line)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref GLS: Regex = Regex::new(r"^2016").unwrap();
    static ref PID: Regex = Regex::new(r"\d{2,3}\((\d+)\):").unwrap();
    static ref DURATION: Regex = Regex::new(r"duration: ([0-9.]+) ms").unwrap();
    static ref STATEMENT: Regex = Regex::new(r"(?:execute.*|statement):(.*)").unwrap();
}

enum MatchResult {
    Ignore,
    QueryStart(i32, String),
    Duration(i32, String),
}

fn analyze_line(line: &str) -> MatchResult {
    use self::MatchResult::*;

    if GLS.is_match(&line) {
        match PID.captures_iter(&line).nth(0) {
            Some(cap) => {
                let pid = cap.at(1).unwrap();
                if DURATION.is_match(&line) {
                    let duration = DURATION.captures_iter(&line).nth(0).unwrap().at(1).unwrap();
                    Duration(pid.parse().unwrap(), duration.to_string())
                } else if STATEMENT.is_match(&line) {
                    let statement = STATEMENT.captures_iter(&line).nth(0).unwrap().at(1).unwrap();
                    QueryStart(pid.parse().unwrap(), statement.to_string())
                } else {
                    Ignore
                }
            }
            None => Ignore,
        }
    } else {
        Ignore
    }
}
```

> Am I correct in thinking that creating a new enum for every call to `analyze_line` is not something to worry about?

It is not something that I would worry about, no. The biggest enum is a few bytes, but not many:

- Vec
- i32
- HashMap
- Writer

`Vec` and `HashMap` are mostly on the heap and only have a few bytes for pointers and the like.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is really good feedback. I'm unfamiliar with some of the syntax you show here but I can see how useful it is. Since you did not mention it, am I correct in think that creating a new enum for every call to `analyze_line` is not something to worry about?